# Problems packaging PyQt application (including QML) using cx_freeze

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I'm attempting to package a PyQt application using cx_freeze. I'm running Python 3.4, Qt 5.6, PyQt 5.5.1 and Cx_freeze 4.3.4 on Windows 7.

There are three pieces to my application, the python/PyQt code, a Qt UI file which contains the GUI elements, and a QML file which runs an interactive map similar to the places_map.qml example. The QML file using the osm map plugin.

My Qt UI file includes a QQuickWidget whose source is the QML file. I'm attempting to package the application, so that others can run it without installing python and Qt. I've created a custom setup.py scripts for cx_freeze to use. However, I keep encountering various ImportErrors related to the QQuickWidget when running my built Exe files. The error occurs when my Python code loads the UI file. I've attempted to include pretty much anything related to QQuickWidgets and the QML code that I can think of in my setup.py file. Initially, the ImportError was missing QQuickWidgets. After adding the SIP QQuickWidget files, the error is now related to QQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget. Below is my setup.py file.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

PYQT5_DIR = "c:/Python34/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/"
include_files = ['TTRMS.ui','places_map.qml',
        (os.path.join(PYQT5_DIR, "qml", "QtQuick.2"), "QtQuick.2"),
        (os.path.join(PYQT5_DIR, "qml", "QtQuick"), "QtQuick"),
        (os.path.join(PYQT5_DIR, "qml", "QtQml"), "QtQml"),
        (os.path.join(PYQT5_DIR, "qml", "Qt"), "Qt"),
        (os.path.join(PYQT5_DIR, "qml", "QtPositioning"), "QtPositioning"),
        (os.path.join(PYQT5_DIR, "qml", "QtLocation"), "QtLocation"),'C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/uic/widget-plugins',
        'C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/plugins/geoservices','C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/sip/PyQt5/QtQuickWidgets',
        'C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/sip/PyQt5/QtQuick']

buildOptions = dict(packages = ['PyQt5.QtQuickWidgets',"atexit","sip","PyQt5.QtCore","PyQt5.QtGui","PyQt5.QtWidgets",
                                    "PyQt5.QtNetwork","PyQt5.QtOpenGL", "PyQt5.QtQml", "PyQt5.QtQuick"], 
                                    excludes = [], includes = ["atexit","re"], include_files = include_files)

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('Main.py', base=base, targetName = 'main.exe')
]

setup(name='TTRMS',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'Travel Time Reliability',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

Here is the error when running my Exe:

[image: ImportError]

I'm not sure what else I need to include in my setup.py in order to package the application properly. I've successfully packaged a small PyQt app with a UI file, but never a UI file which then imports QML through a QQuickWidget. I'm not very knowledgeable about Qt either, so this whole process is new to me. Please let me know if you have any suggestions and let me know if I need to clarify anything. I appreciate any help!

Comment: I am fighting to build a GUI .exe file with python 3+, cx_Freeze for windows 7, with cx_Freeze or other: when I execute my .exe file nothing happens, no error message, no warning, no window opening, nothing... I already set base='Win32GUI' and a bunch of includes. Did you succeed ?